# There is a way to do this operation:

Tags: sql

There is a way to aplicating the following rules above:

From pcest.qtestger:

I just wanna 50% where pcest.codfilial = 1
I also wanna 50% where pcest.codfilial = 2

[image: sql consult]

thanks!

Comment: Please read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome: Please read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Aside from that: you need to provide more details; you've only given a set of requirements, along with a SQL query. You haven't explained what the issue is: errors, output problems, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this example is what you are trying to do. We want to share 50% between group a and 50% between group b.
In your case group A will be when pcest.codfilial = 1 and group B when pcest.codfilial = 2.

```
create table ab(
ab char(1),
id int,
val int);
insert into ab values
('a',1,45),
('a',2,40),
('a',3,65),
('a',4,85),
('b',5,1),
('b',6,5),
('b',7,8),
('b',8,1);
select
ab.ab,
id,
50 * val / t.total as pourcentage
from
ab
left join
(select 
  ab,
  sum(val) total
  from ab
  group by ab) t
on ab.ab = t.ab;
```

> ```
> ab | id | pourcentage
> :- | -: | ----------:
> a  |  1 |           9
> a  |  2 |           8
> a  |  3 |          13
> a  |  4 |          18
> b  |  5 |           3
> b  |  6 |          16
> b  |  7 |          26
> b  |  8 |           3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1ab664a9ad9b1c900881dfc1de272f9)*